# Handling Promise rejection in gulp code

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to minify JS and CSS files using gulp. The script is working for minifying JS files but it's giving below error when I try to minify CSS file

> (node:10533) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: write callback called multiple times
>
> (node:10533) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

The gulp file is as below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var ngmin = require('gulp-ngmin');
var minify_css = require('gulp-minify-css');
var import_css = require('gulp-cssimport');

// ================== Configure this path as per the deployed server ===============
var dev_static_path = '/home/shan/';
var minified_static_path = '/home/shan/minified_assets/';

var ngFiles_site = [
    dev_static_path+'/angular/js/abc.js',
    dev_static_path+'/angular/js/abc-configurator.js',
    dev_static_path+'/angular/js/controller/hostme-ctrl.js',
    dev_static_path+'/angular/js/controller/static-page-ctrl.js'

];
var cssFiles = [
    dev_static_path+'/css/bootstrap.css',
    dev_static_path+'/css/settings.css',
    dev_static_path+'/css/style.css',
    dev_static_path+'/css/custom.css',
    dev_static_path+'/css/site-custom.css'
];
//
//==================================================================================
// minify css files
gulp.task('build-css', function(){
gulp.src(cssFiles)
    .pipe(import_css())
    .pipe(minify_css())
    .pipe(concat('abc.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(minified_static_path))
});
// minify site module js files
gulp.task('build-site-js', function(){
gulp.src(ngFiles_site)
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(concat('abc.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(minified_static_path))
});


// ============================= This is the main execution manager =========================
gulp.task('abcsite',['build-css']);
```

I am not an expert in node JS and I tried changing it to

```
gulp.task('abcsite',['build-css']).catch(function(err){
   console.log(err)
});
```

in a hope to get a promise, but it gave

> TypeError: gulp.task(...).catch is not a function

There are no links available to tell me how to handle promise for a gulp task.

Can anyone help me with this ?

**UPDATE 1**: tried below, didnt work. same error

```
gulp.task('turacos',function(){
  return gulp.src(cssFiles)
    .pipe(import_css())
    .pipe(minify_css())
    .pipe(concat('turacos.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(minified_static_path))
 }).catch(function(err){
console.log(err)
 })
```

Comment: It looks to me like your real error is the use of gulp-cssimport.  I think it can handle only one file input from gulp.src() .  Test it by sending only one file through gulp.src and see if the task works.  The rest of the messages are deprecation warnings and should not prevent the task from completing.

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, passing one file worked. the same code used to work for multiple files earlier. Lemme google and see how to minify others with this one

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `return` the `gulp.src()` call, so gulp will know when the child task has completed:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function(){
    return gulp.src(cssFiles)
    .pipe(import_css())
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, the promise is still not getting returned